# Where can I find full katakana combinations list?

Tags: katakana

Katakana have some combinations beyond low ャ, ュ and ョ that uses low ァ, ィ, ゥ, ェ, and ォ. But I can't find complete list of such combinations. Where are lists like http://goo.gl/Lai88W available, but some other sources like cram.com lists shows more combinations like `テュ` for `tyu`

Does such list exists or it's not standardised in any way and works on "common sense" basis?

Comment: I'm not sure a "complete" list would be very useful, because some of the combinations might hardly ever be used. Other combinations might not be used for any word listed in a reliable dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

I'll make a list myself. Probably won't take too long. Also, I take it that we're talking about Japanese (国語), and standard forms rather than Ainu and colloquialisms, where the combinations are different. You also left out ッ, which i'll list separately for kana it can appear before (not after, because it can occur after anything).

There are lots of combinations that are possible, but not used, and not even standard all the time (particularly ones like クァ), but are technically possible, and thus i've listed them at the end.

ウィ
ウェ
ウォ
ヴァ
ヴィ
ヴェ
ヴォ
キャ
キュ
キョ
ギャ
ギュ
ギョ
シャ
シュ
ショ
ジャ
ジュ
ジョ
チャ
チュ
チョ
ティ
テュ
ディ
デュ
ニャ
ニュ
ニョ
ヒャ
ヒュ
ヒョ
ビャ
ビュ
ビョ
ピャ
ピュ
ピョ
ファ
フィ
フェ
フォ
ミャ
ミュ
ミョ
リャ
リュ
リョ

クァ
クィ
クェ
クォ
グァ
グィ
グェ
グォ
スァ
スィ
スェ
スォ
ズァ
ズィ
ズェ
ズォ
ツァ
ツィ
ツェ
ツォ
トァ
トィ
トゥ
トェ
トォ
ドァ
ドィ
ドゥ
ドェ
ドォ

ッ can occur in front of:
カ行、ガ行、サ行、ザ行、タ行、ダ行、バ行、パ行、sometimes ハ行（例えば：バッハ）. This gives us:

ッカ
ッキ
ック
ッケ
ッコ
ッガ
ッギ
ッグ
ッゲ
ッゴ
ッサ
ッシ
ッス
ッセ
ッソ
ッタ
ッチ
ッツ
ッテ
ット
ッダ
ッデ
ッド
ッハ
ッヒ
ッフ
ッヘ
ッホ
ッバ
ッビ
ッブ
ッベ
ッボ
ッパ
ッピ
ップ
ッペ
ッポ

ッキャ
ッキュ
ッキョ
ッギャ
ッギュ
ッギョ
ッシャ
ッシュ
ッショ
ッジャ
ッジュ
ッジョ
ッチャ
ッチュ
ッチョ
ッティ
ッテュ
ッディ
ッデュ
ッヒャ
ッヒュ
ッヒョ
ッビャ
ッビュ
ッビョ
ッピャ
ッピュ
ッピョ
ッファ
ッフィ
ッフェ
ッフォ

ックァ
ックィ
ックェ
ックォ
ッグァ
ッグィ
ッグェ
ッグォ
ッスァ
ッスィ
ッスェ
ッスォ
ッズァ
ッズィ
ッズェ
ッズォ
ッツァ
ッツィ
ッツェ
ッツォ
ットァ
ットィ
ットゥ
ットェ
ットォ
ッドァ
ッドィ
ッドゥ
ッドェ
ッドォ

Worth noting that pre-WW2 there were some non-standard characters of the ラ行 with dakuten (゛) for transcribing the American r sound, but these aren't used anymore, barely were to begin with, and were pronounced the same way as ラ行 without dakuten.

Comment: Somebody please check I haven't missed any in my list. I can't guarantee I haven't. Also, some of them I've seen, but never formally, so I haven't listed (such as ピィ, セィ etc).

Comment: What this shows is probably that combinations really don't occur in lists. A lot of the ones I showed above COULD be used, but aren't, even though they follow logical rules from ones that are. There are also lots of illogical ones that (at least colloquially) find some usage (especially ones like ピィ).

If you're trying to memorize it, I'd definitely just go by common sense. It's easier, and while listing it is possible, it's not as logical or sensical as when you list out the regular kana tables with 5 rows and 10 columns.